# Run multiple JMS Consumers on different JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jms

I have `JMS` Queue which has hundreds of jobs running and have multiple consumers on the same jvm which are processing to Queue to pick the job and process them, the system  is crashing due to some performance issue and so I want to deploy `JMS` Consumers on different JVM, am new to deploying application or part of application between different `JVM` and would really appreciate if you can provide me some working example of how to do it and how to implement then it would be very helpful to me.

**Update:**

Now there are two ways to consume messages from `JMS Queues` either by creating standalone jms consumers or by creating message driven beans, now I need to have multiple consumers on different jvms that will listen to the queue and process the messages, with standalone `jms consumers`, i can run multiple of those consumers ( just run different jms consumers as standard java program as they have main function) but my question is how can i run multiple of message driven beans on different jvms, meaning how can i run multiple onMessage() functions on different jvms, hope am making some sense here. Kindly advise or point me in the right direction.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have one application running on a JVM and popping messages from a JMS queue, just start it a second time on a second JVM, and voilà... you have two JVMs popping messages from the same queue. Just as you would have two applications connecting to the same database. What else do you need to know?

Comment: It's clear, although I'm not sure why you asked if it was clear. In my experience it's almost *always* the case that multiple JMS consumers run on multiple JVMs, otherwise there isn't much of a point.

Comment: @JBNizet - Right now am using Message Driven Bean to pop the information out of JMS Queue but now i cannot have multiple MDB to process to queue and so i need to create multiple JMS Client that will process the jobs but am not sure how can i achieve this and so if you can share an sample example then it would be very helpful.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ-Can you provide an example of it? I am not sure how to start multiple jms consumers on different jvms using ant script?

Comment: You have n instances of your MDB on JVM1. Just start the same application on JVM2, and you'll have n additional MDB instances. Why do you think you can't have multiple MDBs reading from the queue?

Comment: JB Nizet:To start on different JVM, i need to have main method which gets invoked but in my MDB am having onMessage method and not main method, i might sound not right here but am new to the process of deploying application in multiple jvms and so any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Rachel - are you deplying on an app server?  if so, start 2 app servers with your application running on them.

Comment: yes am deploying on `jboss` application server.

Comment: @jtahlborn: can you go through my comments portion and provide some guidance or pointers in right direction?

Comment: @Rachel - start another jboss app server with the same configuration.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Now I want to integrate the steps to do it from within ant script, so that during build process itself i should be able to deploy application on multiple server, one running on producer and other running the consumer part on the jvm, any clue to move forward on this?